# How to use semaphore in two different independent process?

Tags: c, multithreading, apache, openssl, semaphore

I have a customized OpenSSL engine for RSA. In that OpenSSL engine, I have a shared resource that I want to use atomically. The problem is, when `mod_ssl` calls this engine from an Apache webserver with multi-thread, each thread initializes this engine and tries to use that shared resource, causing an undefined result.

I was thinking to use `semaphore` to lock this shared resource, but again the problem is I can't initialize `semaphore` from within the engine because each `mod_ssl` thread initializes a new engine instance, so initializing a semaphore within the engine itself will not work.

I was wondering if there is a way to initialize a `semaphore` globally which each thread can access? I read about `named semaphores` in [sem_overview](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview); it seems like this may help in my case, but I do not understand how it works.

So, any idea, how to initialize a global semaphore to sync two threads?

Comment: Making your code serialize on the shared resource will slow the multithreaded systems down.  You would do best to get rid of that dependency.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, thanks. Yes, I do understand it. However, getting rid of that dependency is not an option for me. I'm okay with a little performance degradation.

Comment: The System V IPC Semaphores ([`semget()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semget.html), [`semop()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semop.html), [`semctl()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/semctl.html)) can be used between processes.  They are defined in POSIX.  I'm less familiar with the other modern POSIX semaphore functions ([`sem_open()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html), [`sem_post()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_post.html)
et al).